# Content-Disposition HTTP Header

Tags: rest, header, response-headers

A website returns JSON as response but the response header says the content-disposition type is attachment is there any specific reason for it..

I am creating a RestAPI should I do the same

does this have any security related or any other specific purpose should it be done

Comment: You should review: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266.html

Comment: okay I will check